# recaptcha stuck on password protected page wordpress 4.8

Tags: php, wordpress, passwords, recaptcha, protected

I have this password protected wordpress 4.8 page, test link: https://www.covr.nl/en/passwordprotectedtest/ - password = "password" - but it keeps hanging in the integrated reCaptcha of wordpress, and I don't see any way to disable or fix it. 
Does anyone have a clue what could be the issue? 
Or is this a general issue with the latest WP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by the setting in my multi lang plugin (qtranslate-X) that stops the /nl/ (default language) to show in the url. So for Dutch (in my case) the url doenst at the /nl/, this way the wp-login.php?action=postpass redirects proparly. Perhaps handy for someone else with the problem!